# How to get selected

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

first of all its my first question in Stackoverflow, because im hardstuck in a problem right now. So hopefully someone can help me with that.

**The project:** I am building a Product Configurator for a Website. The main goal is, that customers can configurate their product and the options they selected are automatically placed in a Contact Form.

The site:  https://soundgreets.com/produkt/konfigurator/

I am working on Wordpress with Elementor. The Plugin I used for the configurator is: "Woocommerce Extra Product options"

**My Problem:** I need to get the ID's of the specific selected containers and fill it automatically in the Form down below.

**The site:**  https://soundgreets.com/produkt/konfigurator/

Does anyone know how i can do this? Maybe in a .php file? Or in elementor? I did some massive CSS on the site, so that it looks like it is right now.
This Selector is to select all containers of the Dropdowns.

```
.tc-extra-product-options .cpf-type-select .tmcp-field-wrap label.fullwidth select{
color: red;
```

}

**What i also tried** is to use Elementors Html Code-widget to get the variable of the specific Id of a container.

This didnt work: the output is "undefined"

```
<html>

<head>
  <script>
var e = document.getElementById("tmcp_select_160362915b5ef2");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
document.write(strUser)
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope someone has an idea on this.

thanks in advance

Berkan

*PS: The site could look a bit messy i am sorry for that*

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you can have the details of what the customers have configured?
You must retrieve the value of the selects and put them in the database, before displaying them in a form.

Comment: Correct, thats the idea. Is there no way to basically just take the ID of the selects. Get the text of them and put the variable in the Form, maybe with shortcode?

Comment: You need to store the values, doing an ajax request seems like a good start.